# What is rolling sum and how to impliment it in Informatica and my requirement is as follows?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can someone pl tell me what is rolling sum and how to implement it in Informatica?

My requirement is as below:(Given by client)

**ETI_DUR   :** 
    SUM(CASE WHEN AGENT_EXPNCD_DIM.EXCEPTION_CD='SYS/BLDG ISSUES ETI' THEN IEX_AGENT_DEXPN.SCD_DURATION ELSE 0 END)

**ETI_30_DAY    :**
    ROLLING SUM(CASE WHEN (SYSDATE-IEX_AGENT_DEXPN.ROW_DT)<=30 AND AGENT_EXPNCD_DIM.EXCEPTION_CD = 'SYS/BLDG ISSUES ETI' 
    THEN IEX_AGENT_DEXPN.SCD_DURATION ELSE 0 END)

**ETI_30_DAY_OVRG   :**
    CASE  WHEN ETI_DUR > 0 THEN 
    CASe 
    WHEN  ROLLINGSUM(ETI_DUR_30_DAY FOR LAST 29 DAYS) BETWEEN 0 AND 600 AND ROLLINGSUM(ETI_DUR_30_DAY FOR LAST 29 DAYS) + ETI_DUR > 600 THEN  ROLLINGSUM(ETI_DUR_30_DAY FOR LAST 30 DAYS) - 600 
    WHEN  ROLLINGSUM(ETI_DUR_30_DAY FOR LAST 29 DAYS) > 600    THEN ETI_DUR 
    ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0 END

And i have implemented as below in Informatica.

**Expression Transformation:**

**o_ETI_DUR--** IIF(UPPER(EXCEPTION_CD_AGENT_EXPNDIM)='SYS/BLDG ISSUES ETI',SCD_DURATION,0)

**o_ETI_29_DAY--**  IIF(DATE_DIFF(TRUNC(SYSDATE),trunc(SCHD_DATE),'DD') <=29 AND UPPER(EXCEPTION_CD_AGENT_EXPNDIM) = 'SYS/BLDG ISSUES ETI' ,SCD_DURATION,0)

**o_ETI_30_DAY --** IIF(DATE_DIFF(TRUNC(SYSDATE),trunc(SCHD_DATE),'DD') <=30 AND UPPER(EXCEPTION_CD_AGENT_EXPNDIM) = 'SYS/BLDG ISSUES ETI' ,SCD_DURATION,0)

**Aggregator  transformation:**

**o_ETI_30_DAY_OVRG:**
    IIF(sum(i_ETI_DUR) > 0, 
    IIF((sum(i_ETI_29_DAY)>=0 and sum(i_ETI_29_DAY)<=600) and (sum(i_ETI_29_DAY)+sum(i_ETI_DUR)) > 600,
     sum(i_ETI_30_DAY) - 600, 
    IIF(sum(i_ETI_29_DAY)>600,sum(i_ETI_DUR),0)),0)

But is not working. Pl help ASAP.

Thanks a lot....!

Comment: What's your question? What is a rolling sum **or** how to implement all these requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Rolling sum is just the sum of some amount over a fixed duration of time. For example, everyday you can calculate the sum of expense for last 30 days.

I guess you can use an aggregator to calculate ETI_DUR, ETI_30_DAY and ETI_29_DAY. After that, in an expression you can implement the logic for ETI_30_DAY_OVRG. Note that you cannot write an IIF expression like that in an aggregator. Output ports must use an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rolling sum example:

```
count, rolling_sum
1,1
2,3
5,8
1,9
1,10
```

Basically it is the sum of the values listed previously. To implement it in Informatica use 'local variables' (variable port in expression transformation) as follows:

input port: `count`
variable port: `v_sum_count = v_sum_count + count`
output port: `rolling_sum = v_sum_count`

Answer (score 1):

we have a moving sum function defined in Numerical functions in Expression transformation:

```
MOVINGSUM(n as numeric, i as integer, [where as expression]).
```

Please check if it helps.

Comment: please format your answer and provide some more details,and read FAQ to give answers in a suitable way